# ajax send a request in ajax and get the response

Tags: php, ajax

Morning! Please i will like to get some data from mySQL(like getting the number of rows of a mySQL table using ajax). Please how can i do it? Here are my 2 pages. The first one send a number to the php page and the second one do a request to the database and send the result to the page in ajax(the first one). The table voisin_par_distance has 3 columns: cel_id, cel_id_1 and cel_id_2 Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script>
var xhr1 = new XMLHttpRequest();
var i=1;
var j=4;
xhr1.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr1.status == 200 && xhr1.readyState == 4) {
        document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = xhr1.responseText;
    }
};
xhr1.open('GET', 'test.php?i='+i+'&j='+j, false);
xhr1.send('');
</script>
<?php
  // I would line to get for example the number of rows of table voisin_par_distance which is returned by test.php
  $m = (int) $_GET['n'];
  echo $m;
?>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is the php page which is in the same directory.

```
<?php
$dbname='BD';
try {
  $bdd = new PDO( 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=BD', 'root', '' );
}
catch ( PDOException $e ) {
  die("Could not connect to the database $dbname :" . $e->getMessage() );
}

$i = (int) $_GET['i'];
$j = (int) $_GET['j'];
  //to select the number of rows of my table
$req = $bdd->prepare("SELECT serveur FROM voisin_par_distance WHERE cel_id_1=':cel_id_1' AND cel_id_2=':cel_id_2'");
$req->execute( array(
  'cel_id_1' => $i,
  'cel_id_2' => $j
  ) );
$nbre_ligne = count( $req );

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script>
var nbre_ligne = <?php echo $nbre_ligne; ?>
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var a = 2;
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.status == 200 && xhr.readyState == 4) {
        document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
    }
};
xhr.open('GET', 'show_map.php?n='+nbre_ligne);
xhr.send('');
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best and Easy way to use ajax:

```
 $.ajax({// on an event
    type: "GET",
    url: "test.php", #with valid path
    data: {col1: "value1", col2: "value2"},
    cache: false,
    success: function (responce) { 
     // alert your response to check data
        if (responce.length > 0) {
            var data = JSON.parse(responce); // Parse JSON
           //Your logic here
        }
    }
});
```

In Your PHP file, return data in json format. e.g.

```
echo json_encode(array('col1' => $val, 'col2' => $val2));
exit;
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: thanks for your help. the message in console says: ReferenceError: $ is not defined
[En savoir plus]
my_page:559:1
Error: Graph container element not found